# How to ensure all x-axis labels appear with .Net Visual Studio 2010 chart?

Tags: c#

[image: chart]

This is the code I used:

```
 MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
 MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" SELECT `Numero outil`, date FROM `outil`  group by `Numero outil`   ;", conDataBase);
 MySqlDataReader myReader;
 conDataBase.Open();
 myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

 while (myReader.Read())
 {
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString ("Numero outil"),myReader.GetDateTime ("date"));

  }
```

Comment: Isn't this just because the labels don't fit so that chart drops some to make the rest readable? Try rotating the labels to 45°.

Comment: What type of chart control are you using, i.e. who makes it and what version is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can control how many `X-Axis` labels are shown by setting the `Interval` property:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

The default is automatic, which tries to fit them in but as they are a bit long only every 2nd label gets shown.

There are various ways to control the display if the don't fit:

- Change the Font
- Display them at an angle
- Display them in two rows..

Do look into [Labels in Chart Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx) and also [`AxisX.LabelStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.labelstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more detials..!

And you can turn on `SmartLabels` which tries to find a smart display automatically..

But the smartest way is alway to think ahead and create the values with a nice display in mind. They look like random test data so far. Do put in some effort so you will know just what you actually want to show..