# Chart vb.net not shows date below the series

Tags: vb.net, charts

i have a form in vb.net project where i have a chart control which shows the daily sales of the shop.
Now the issue is that the chart not showing the sale dates below its series.

some dates are visible but some are not (as shown in image.)

[image]

Note:- in my Sql database all dates are exist from 1st to 10th but chart shows only odd dates i.e 1,3,5,7,9 etc
please help

i tried all i.e search in internet etc but in vain

Comment: IIRC, you have to select the `ChartArea`, its `Axis` (`AxisX` / `AxisY)` objects should have an `Interval` Property that, IIRC2, should be set to 1 -- Sorry, quite vague, I haven't used this Control in a while. Maybe someone else can be more precise

Comment: To add to Jimi's comment: [How to ensure all x-axis labels appear with .Net Visual Studio 2010 chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414777/how-to-ensure-all-x-axis-labels-appear-with-net-visual-studio-2010-chart)

Answer (score 0):

With this short sample code can set the interval on the axis.

```
        Dim mych As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
        mych = New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

        mych.Series.Add("Firstseries")
        mych.Series("Firstseries").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
        Dim myarr As Array = {5, 7, 9, 12, 3, 45, 4, 43, 23}
        For Each par In myarr
            mych.Series("Firstseries").Points.Add(par)
        Next par
        mych.Series("Firstseries").XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date
        mych.Series("Firstseries").LabelAngle = 0

        Dim charea = mych.ChartAreas.Add("newarea")
        charea.AxisX.Interval = 0   'This set to AutoMode.
        charea.AxisX.Interval = 1
        charea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
        mych.Series(0).ChartArea = "newarea"
        mych.Show()
        Dim myform = New Form
        myform.Controls.Add(mych)
        myform.ShowDialog()
        Stop
```

**If the Chart is created in Excel:**

Right click on `Horizontal (Category) Axis` and choose `Format Axis ...`

[image]

In `Interval between labels:` either select `Automatic` or set `Specify interval unit:` to `1`.